# Why RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME is used for @Deprecated annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

Below is the documentation of [@Deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation.

```
/**
 * A program element annotated &#64;Deprecated is one that programmers
 * are discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous,
 * or because a better alternative exists.  Compilers warn when a
 * deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code.
 *
 */
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, LOCAL_VARIABLE, METHOD, PACKAGE, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface Deprecated {
}
```

**My question is:** `@Deprecated` (a marker annotation) is for the programmer to indicate that this method/ field/ package... is discouraged from using it, then why `RetentionPolicy` is set to `RUNTIME` why not `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` is used?

Answer (score 1):

Reflection in Java can be used to read annotations of a class at runtime. If `RetentionPolicy.CLASS` were used then the `@Deprecated` annotation would not be available to be read like this.

As an example, a reflective program might read in a user-provided class, and execute all non-deprecated static methods without any arguments. Maybe someone can come up with a better example than that. Some reason why a unit testing framework might make use of it perhaps.